# Take the values of some specific date and hour of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a table from a csv file where the table must contain only the data of 2016-02-19 and only one row per hour.

For example for that dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

I already have the data from 2016-02-19 but I couldn't filter by a time delta of 1 hour. The result must be only the data of 2016-02-19 00:00:00, 2016-02-19 01:00:00, 2016-02-19 02:00:00, etc.

```
train.set_index(pd.to_datetime(train.timestamp))
df = train["02/19/2016"]
```

So far I've done like this, if anyone knows how to filter it by hours too it would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to get one row per hour when there are multiple building ids with the same timestamp?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and read [ask] your question is vague and needs refinement. Think as if you're presenting this to a peer or teacher, you need to be crystal clear with what you need, no second guessing from others.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not a minimal reproducible example that we could use to work with your dataframe, I'm gonna guess what your dataframe is based on the image you have provided. I believe what you need is [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) which is a pandas function. this function is used when you want to resample your time series data set. I believe you will simply need to call the below cell on your dataframe:

```py
train.set_index(pd.to_datetime(train.timestamp))
df = train["02/19/2016"]
df.resample("H").sum()
```